# get blog page url in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

The blog page on my WordPress website is set to be a different page other than the home page. I want to get the link to this blog page from any other pages.

How can I get blog page url?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use `get_option` of `page_for_posts` to get the page ID to either assign it to a variable or to echo it.

```
<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>
```

For more information of the default `get_option` visit: [Option Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference)

Answer (score 22):

We can use [get_post_type_archive_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/) since [WordPress 4.5](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/since/4.5.0/)

```
get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' );
```

Answer (score 3):

$posts_page_url is the url to blog page and $posts_page_title is the page title

```
<?php
$posts_page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts');
$posts_page = get_page( $posts_page_id);
$posts_page_title = $posts_page->post_title;
$posts_page_url = get_page_uri($posts_page_id  );
?>
```

More details refer the link - http://www.queness.com/code-snippet/7935/how-to-get-url-for-blog-page-when-using-static-homepage

Answer (score 3):

To get the Blog URL you can use the below code.

```
get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```

If you are using WordPress 4.5+ then you can use the below code which will work for any post type.

```
get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call your url with this extention and all blog posts are displayed.

https://www.yourdomain.com/?post_type=post

Answer (score 2):

If your blog url is https://www.yourdomain.com/blog, you can use:

```
echo site_url('/blog');
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
<?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) . '">Our Blog</a>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the curious, once you get the post id as mentioned by [@ManthanDave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5537400/manthan-dave),

```php
e.g $id = get_option( 'page_for_posts');
```

you can use functions to get properties like:

```php
get_the_title($id);
get_the_permalink($id);

// and so on
```